# What is the purpose of adding docker repository key to apt-key?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, apt

I am trying to install docker in my ubuntu 14.04, and i followed the below link.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-getting-started

In this link, It is mentioned that we need to add docuker repository key. I could not understand what is the use of this, and why to add?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the binaries will be downloaded by a `https`-Connection. You're importing their key in order to validate the connection and the transfered data/package.

Its also sayed in the documentary

> Add docker repository key to apt-key for *package verification*:

Mainly as a server hoster you want to trust the packages you're going to install on your machine. With this key you can prove that the given package was made by the 'right' guys ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Partially i understood. What would have happened if there is no such concept like adding key for package verification?. I assume this adding key is something that resolves fundamental issue of security. What is that the issue it resolves?

Comment: As such, it does not need these procedures to download the package. It's just to verify you got the package originating from the guys who have signed the package (in this case the docker guys).
If somebody else wants to foist you a manipulated package (e.g. a hacked docker daemon which actually spies on you) you would notice it because it wasn't signed with the right key (aslong a good encryption algorithm was used)